# Best way to calculate a trend

Tags: algorithm, statistics, data-analysis, trend

I am coding an app that allows users to vote (`market_trend_up += 1` for example), the app then fetches the accumulated data (`trend_up_votes = 632; trend_down_votes = 236`), analyzes and displays the resulting trend (`if up_votes > down_votes { trend = up }`).

What would you advise me to do to refresh the trends regularly? I thought about reinitializing the votes every 6h for instance but then the first voter will decide of the trend by himself.

Would letting the votes accumulate always provide the current trend? Thank you!

Comment: what about saving timestamp data to vote and than calculate changes over time...

Comment: @shahaf I am also saving a timestamp (initially to calculate the elapsed time since the first vote and reset when 6 hours passed). What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: excellent so you basically can draw a graph of votes per the time, I suggest you looking at the graph and see what you define as trend, you can compute the change relative to day, hour, any duration before or define trend as N points in time before which up_vote > down_vote and such...

Comment: Thanks! It seems kind of obvious actually even if this is going to be really expensive to save all that data on the server haha